# I have trouble with "Endless Loop"

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I'm new to this. My problem is that I have a very easy code, but I'm going into an endless loop in one of every 3 runs. What could be my fault?

I thought the last loop would be a problem. I've reduced the number of the last loop by 1. So the option was increased but this time the second loop entered the endless loop.

```
import UIKit

var firstArray = [Int]()
var column1 = [1,3,7]
var column2 = [2,9,8]
var column3 = [5,8,6]

while firstArray.count != 3
{
     let number = Int.random(in: 1 ..< 10)
    while !firstArray.contains(number) && !column1.contains(number)
    {firstArray.append(number)}
}
while firstArray.count != 6
{
    let number2 = Int.random(in: 1 ..< 10)
    while !firstArray.contains(number2) && !column2.contains(number2)
    { firstArray.append(number2)}
}
while firstArray.count != 9
{
    let number3 = Int.random(in: 1 ..< 10)
    if !firstArray.contains(number3) && !column3.contains(number3)
    { firstArray.append(number3)}
}


print(firstArray)
```

When it doesn't enter the endless loop, it can give results in 1 second. But it's usually an endless loop.

Comment: So many loops? What is your exact requirement ?

Comment: That's because firstArray is empty to start with?

Comment: To create a new column different from the columns given, like Sudoku logic. therefore the first array must be empty.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal here? Just to create a new random sudoku board using all digits from 1-9? (btw you got a duplicate '8' in your original board in this case)

Comment: yes, it is 3x3 in the middle part, it should be controlled from other 3x3 boards.

Comment: He will run into an infinite loop, if he can only add numbers in the last loop which are exempted in coulmn 3. For example, if he has a 6 as the last number left, he can never add it. Create a playground and run your program there. Then you should notice this error.